# Finding the norm of the linear functional $f(x)=\int_{-1}^0 x(t) \, dt - \int_0^1 x(t) \, dt$ on $C[-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This is a basic question of functional analysis, but I want to know how to...

> Find the norm of the linear functional $f$ defined on $C[-1,1]$ by $$f(x)=\int_{-1}^0 x(t) \, dt - \int_0^1 x(t) \, dt.$$

If anything, I know of the theorem from my textbook (FA by Kreszig, page 105):

> Let us choose the space $C[a,b]$. Then $f$ is defined by $$f(x) = \int_a^b x(t) \, dt. \tag{$x \in C[a,b]$}$$ We see that $f$ is linear. We prove that $f$ is bounded and has the norm $\|f\|=b-a$. We obtain $$|f(x)|=\left|\int_a^b x(t) \, dt \right| \le (b-a) \max_{t \in[a,b]} |x(t)| = (b-a) \|x\|.$$ Taking the supremum over all $x$ of norm $1$, we obtain $\|f\| \le b-a$. To get $\|f\| \ge b-a$, we choose the particular $x=x_0=1$, note that $\|x_0\|=1$ and use the previous formula $|f(x)| \le \|f\| \|x\|$: $$\|f\| \ge \frac{|f(x_0)|}{\|x_0\|}=|f(x_0)|=\int_a^b dt = b-a.$$

Can I use what was said above (copied from textbook) to apply it to the $f(x)$ I'm given? i.e. $$\|f(x)\|=\left\|\int_{-1}^0 x(t) \, dt - \int_0^1 x(t) \, dt \right\|$$
I don't really have the slightest idea on this though.

Comment: That is the right first step.  Your goal is to infer an upper bound on $\| f(x) |$ in terms of $\| x \|$.  Then, as in the example you included, typically you produce an individual function or a sequence of functions showing that the bound is either attained or can be arbitrarily close to attained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every continuous linear functional $\Phi$ on $C[-1,1]$ can be written as
$$
               \Phi(f) = \int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\,d\mu(t)
$$
where $\mu$ is a function of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$. When normalized so that $\mu(x+0)=\mu(x)$ for $-1 \le x < 1$, then $\|\Phi\|=\mbox{Var}(\mu)$ is the total variation of $\mu$. For your functional, $\mu$ is the continuous function
$$
                   \mu(t) = \int_{-1}^{t}\{\chi_{[-1,0]}(s)-\chi_{[0,1]}(s)\}\,ds,
$$
a function of bounded variation whose total variation $\mbox{Var}(\mu)$ is the $L^{1}$ norm of the density function:
$$
                  \|\mu\| = \int_{-1}^{1}|\chi_{[-1,0]}(s)-\chi_{[0,1]}(s)|\,ds = 2.
$$
That is, $|\Phi(f)| \le 2\|f\|$ for all $f \in C[-1,1]$, and $2$ is the smallest bound.

Comment: Excuse me sir but could you explain to me what do you mean $$||μ||= \int_{-1}^{1}|χ_{[-1,0]}(s)-χ_{[0,1]}(s)|ds$$ I mean what do you mean $χ_{[-1,0]}(s)$ and $χ_{[0,1]}(s)$ what are these ?

Comment: A function $\chi_{S}$ is the characteristic function of the set $S$; it is $1$ for $x \in S$ and is $0$ otherwise. Every continuous linear functional $\Phi$ on $C[a,b]$ has the form $\Phi(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dg(t)$, where $g$ is a function of bounded variation; $g$ is unique when some normalization is required such as $g(a)=0$ and $g(t+0)=g(t)$ for $a \le t < b$. Then $\|\Phi\|=\|g\|$, where $\|g\|$ is the variation of the function of bounded variation $g$. If $g(t)=\int_{a}^{t}h(t)dt$, then it is well know that the variation of $g$ is $\|g\|=\int_{a}^{b}|h(t)|dt$.

Comment: @Functionalanalysis : I forgot to ping you in the last remark.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Can you please recommend a book or a course for things you explained? these are not covered in Kreszig. I know its been a long time since the question is asked, but i think a reader completely new to the field could relate to me.

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna : I learned by reading *Functional Analysis* by Bachmann and Narici. Their proof was an elementary application of the Hahn-Banach theorem used to extend the functional from $C[0,1]$ to $\tilde{\Phi}$ on all bounded functions on $[0,1]$. Then $g(t) = \tilde{\Phi}(\chi_{[0,t]})$. It was a very clever and simple argument leading to a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, avoiding measure theory entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, by any chance do you also have a recommendation for learning geometric aspects of functional analysis, more on the lines of a visual interpretation?

Comment: @JosyulaKrishna : I can't think of any reference that particularly concentrates on the geometric aspects.

Comment: Okay, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here you can estimate more:
\begin{align}|f(x)| &= \left|\int_{-1}^0x(t)\,dt-\int_0^1x(t)\,dt\right| \\ &\le\left|\int_{-1}^0x(t)\,dt\right|+\left|\int_0^1x(t)\,dt\right| \\ 
&\le\sup_{t\in[-1,0]}|x(t)|+\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)| \\
&\le 2\cdot \sup_{t\in[-1,1]}|x(t)| \\
&=2\|x(t)\|_\infty\end{align}  thus $\|f\|\le 2$

Now you must show $\|f\|\ge 2$, and you will obtain $\|f\|=2$.

I thought about this some more, and to my knowledge there is no $x^*\in C[-1,1]$ s.t $\|x^*\|_\infty=1$ and $|f(x)|=2$, such an example would be $y(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{if $-1\le t\le 0$};\\
        -1 & \mbox{if $0\lt t\le 1$}.\end{array} \right. $ but of course here $y\not\in C[-1,1]$, but if we consider the sequence $x^*_n(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
         1 & \mbox{if $-1\le t\le \frac{-1}{n}$};\\
         -nt & \mbox{if $\frac{-1}{n}\lt t\lt\frac{1}{n}$};\\
        -1 & \mbox{if $\frac{1}{n}\le t\le 1$}.\end{array} \right.$ 
Here $x^*_n\in C[-1,1]$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Then we see that (by definition of sup) $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in C[-1,1]:\|x\|=1}|f(x)|\ge|f(x^*_n)|\,\forall n\in \Bbb N$.

Since (if my calculations are correct) $|f(x^*_n)|=|2+\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2}{n}|$, we obtain $\|f\|\ge|2+\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2}{n}|\,\forall n\in\Bbb N\Rightarrow \|f\|\ge 2$, now of course combining the fact that $\|f\|\le 2$ and $\|f\|\ge 2\Rightarrow \|f\|=2$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. We showed that $|f(x)| \le 2\| x\|$. Why are we concluding in the first part that $\|f\| \le 2$?

Comment: because then $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in C[-1,1]}\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}\le\frac{2\|x\|}{\|x\|}=2$

Comment: Based on your comment, are we really trying to estimate $|f(x)|$, and not $\|f(x)\|$, so we can also estimate $\|f\|$? (I took the liberty to fix that in your answer.)

Comment: yeah that seems right :)

Comment: we norm is $C[-1,1]$ meant to be endowed with? is it the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm?

Comment: I think the book denotes $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ as just $\| \cdot \|$. I think that applies to $C[a,b]$, right?

Comment: By the way, for the other inequality, I got, for $\|x_0\|=1$, $$\|f\| \ge \frac{|f(x_0)|}{\|x_0\|} = |f(x_0)| = \int_{-1}^1 \, dt = 2$$

Comment: @legâteauaufromage I've been trying to think of an example and sadly $x_0=1$ doesn't work, since $|\int_{-1}^0\,dt-\int_0^1\,dt|=0\ne 2$

Comment: @legâteauaufromage see my edit

Comment: I know this is a very late comment, but I wanted to mention that this answer is much more "in-context" with Kreyszig's book than the "accepted" answer above.